# git clone fails while installing linuxbrew, gnutls error -9 paket with unexpected length was received

Tags: linux, git, homebrew

i run this:

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -k -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

it gets to "git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" then always fails with this:

error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.

this happens when the command is run separately

in full:

````
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod 755 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/zsh /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at 89f3a3326 Merge pull request #7145 from dawidd6/linux-mac-sdk-if-needed
==> Tapping homebrew/core
Cloning into '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 298, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (298/298), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (165/165), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core` exited with 128.
Error: Failure while executing; `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew tap homebrew/core` exited with 1.
Failed during: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew update --force
Warning: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin is not in your PATH.
==> Installation successful! //you are mocking me and i dislike it

==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate formulae and cask analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics
No analytics data has been sent yet (or will be during this `install` run).

==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations

==> Next steps:
- Run `brew help` to get started
- Further documentation: 
    https://docs.brew.sh
- Install the Homebrew dependencies if you have sudo access:
  Debian, Ubuntu, etc.
    sudo apt-get install build-essential
  Fedora, Red Hat, CentOS, etc.
    sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
  See https://docs.brew.sh/linux for more information.
- Configure Homebrew in your /home/jack/.profile by running
    echo 'eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /home/jack/.profile
- Add Homebrew to your PATH
    eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
- We recommend that you install GCC by running:
    brew install gcc```
````

Comment: Quite a bit out there on Google and SO for this issue, https://sarathblogs.blogspot.com/2017/02/solved-fix-for-git-clone-failure-due-to.html

Comment: that's the same as most other answers i have found; i tried it anyway, though i think i have already made these changes, and got the same result

Comment: Can you clone it by hand?

Comment: same error comes up

Comment: I feel like a fool now but, I just downloaded from github then put it in the directory it was cloning into. Not really a fix but it works now.

Comment: Same issue - I tried lots of things: recompiling Git with openssl, increasing `http.postbuffer`, setting `http.sslVerify` to false. Nothing worked. Then I tried on another machine with different OS and the same issue happened. Makes me think the issue is on linuxbrew side. Like your "fix" though!